# Convergence in Mean Square $\Longrightarrow$ Convergence in Probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I'm reading through some notes on Probability, and the statement is made that:

> If random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ converge to $X$ in mean square, then they also converge in probability.

Can someone please explain why this is the case? Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix $\delta>0$. Then 
$$\delta^2 P(|X_n-X|\geq \delta)=\delta^2 P(|X_n-X|^2\geq \delta^2)\leq \int_{\Omega}|X_n-X|^2dP,$$
so $P(|X_n-X|\geq \delta)\leq \frac 1{\delta^2}\int_{\Omega}|X_n-X|^2dP$ and we can conclude since the las integral converges to $0$.

Comment: Many thanks. What rule are you invoking to say that $\delta^2 P(|X_n-X|^2\geq \delta^2)\leq \int_{\Omega}|X_n-X|^2dP$?

Comment: You integrate over the set $\{|X_n-X|\geq \delta\}$ the constant $\delta^2$. On this set it's smaller than $|X_n-X|^2$, and the integral over this set is small than the integral on $\Omega$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that.